# How do I force window.location.href to redirect as JS Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a controller create action called by a JS/ajax call.

> Started POST "/some_domain/some_controller" for at
> Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1 Processing by
> SomeController#create as JS

But when I try to send back a redirect to another controllers edit action using window.location.href, it rdirects as HTML. I want it to call the controller action as JS.

**Controller**

render js: "window.location.href =' #{edit_different_controller_path(@object.id)}'"

> Started GET "/some_domain/different_controller/186/edit" for 115.70.22.192 at
> Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1 Processing by
> DifferentController#edit as HTML

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The better way to do this would be to `render :json` with the object id. Then your ajax complete handler can do the redirect since it has the ID needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the format arg to the options of your url helper.

```rb
return redirect_to some_helper_url format: :js
```

It'll send back a url with the appropriate .js on the end.

Comment: Thanks Nita. Now my response is correct content type (JS) but I get a ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest (Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript.